# MapReduce (Hadoop): A basic implementation of table in Hive or HBase

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, hive

I have been reading on Hadoop file system and trying to understand what it is. I have a basic understanding. I know RDBMS quite well, what I am struggling to understand is how a simple table can be implemented in say for example HBase.

From a Cloudera free tutorial, I learnt that HBase is column oriented, how do you implement a column oriented table (is it called a table?)?

How do you implement a simple users table with columns id, username, password (or can you not do something like this?)?

Thanks!

Comment: You should accept the answer if you find them helpful..

Comment: @Sherry, sorry I didn't accept the answer because I was still reading the link

Comment: @Kev: The following is the question:

How do you implement a simple users table with columns id, username, password (or can you not do something like this?)? (In HBase for example)

[closed as not a real question] -- If you don't understand what's being asked here, then you need to learn English. :-)

Comment: My english is perfectly fine. As to why I closed it, what I didn't see in the question was any evidence of having tried to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first of all you need to understand Why are you using HBase and what is column oriented approach.
You will see everywhere that while creating a design for HBase you will create a 
`column` and then a

```
column family
```

Now the thing is you have to keep in mind that HBase is for very large scale data and when you need mapreduce jobs and fast retrievals.I can;t cover HBase column oriented approach here but i suggest you [this link](http://hbase.apache.org/book/quickstart.html).I hope it will be helpful for you :)
feel free to ask question if you have any confusion